# Is there a script which fixes git-diff --check warnings?

Tags: git, removing-whitespace, git-diff

git-diff has a cool feature documented as:

> --check Warn if changes introduce trailing whitespace or an indent that uses a space before a tab. Exits with non-zero status if problems
>   are found. Not compatible with --exit-code.

I usually run git-diff with --check before committing and fix all warning to keep the code nice and tidy.
Is there any script or tool which can parse the output of git-diff --check and automatically fix all warnings?

Comment: I didn't want to fiddle about with committing and amending but then I realised that you can use `vim` to simplify this: if you load the output of `git diff --check` into a buffer then you can use the `:cbuffer` (`:cb`) command to treat the buffer as a `vim` error list, and `vim` will then let you navigate the list of errors. In my case all the errors were the same type so I just recorded a macro to fix them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a script, per se, but you can pretty easily make use of `git apply --whitespace=fix` to clean up the patch. Off the top of my head, something like the following:

```
git commit -m 'this has diff --check errors'
git format-patch --stdout HEAD | git apply --index --whitespace=fix -
git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

If you wanted this automatically, you might try turning that into a post-commit hook, with a bit more care.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the way to go

Comment: This link has such a solution: http://makandracards.com/makandra/11541-how-to-not-leave-trailing-whitespace-using-your-editor-or-git

Comment: I have used the following command for this now (adapted from the link in the above comment): `git format-patch -1 --stdout HEAD > stage.patch && git apply --index -R stage.patch && git apply --index --whitespace=fix stage.patch`